# Prestablog - Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I use Prestablog on Prestashop 1.6.11 and recently when I create or modify an article, it is impossible for me to click on the "Choose a file" button of the main image. I do not understand why nothing happens. No window opens.

In the Javascript console, I get the following error, but I do not know if it is related to my problem:

```
 tinymce.inc.1.6.js:61 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
    at tinySetup (tinymce.inc.1.6.js:61)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?tab=AdminModules&configure=prestablog&token=4ff8fc2…&activeget=0&…:1091)
    at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
```

A problem with updating products since the prestashop 1.6 update has been corrected. At first I thought the problem came from here but, I have a test server with exactly the same files as the production server and I have no error. Everything works perfectly. The only files that are not common are the cache files.

How can I solve my problem? Should I try to reinitialize the system cache? If so how do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the following 2 files:

```
/js/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js
/js/tiny_mce/tinymce.min.js
```

Comment: Thanks, I have replace `tinymce.min.js` and `tiny_mce.js` into prestablog module folder.

Answer (score 0):

too late answer i guess but if after replacing the `tiny_mce.js` and `tiny_mcs.min.js` still the error is same then add following code at given location :

```
prestashop/js/admin/tinymce_inc.js
```

replace this :

```
tinyMCE.init(config);
```

with this :

```
if (typeof tinyMCE !== 'undefined' && typeof tinyMCE != undefined && tinyMCE != "" && tinyMCE != null) {
        tinyMCE.init(config);
}
```

then go to AdvanceParameters/Performance in Back Office and clear cache and reload product page.

hope this fix your issue as it fix mine.

> Note:- this code is allowed to skip tiny_MCE error so all the other js works, but tiny mce editor is not appear whenever this error is skipped. you can get only simple textarea on product descriptions like